# Update a record using Linq by passing a value object

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to program in 3 tier method .So i create a value object layer and i create a user object value something like this :

```
public class VOuser:MainClass
{
    public string _username;
    public string _password;
    public string _email;
    public string _mobile;
    public DateTime _dateOfRegister;
    public string _name;
    public string _family;

    public VOuser()
    {
        _BUuser=new BUUser();
    }
    public EnumUserPermission Permission
    {
        get { return _permission; }
        set { _permission = value; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { if(value=="")message("لطفا نام کاربری را وارد کنید"); _username = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { if (value == "")message("لطفا کلمه عبور را وارد کنید"); _password = value; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set { if (value == "")message("لطفا رایانامه را وارد کنید"); _email = value; }
    }

    public string Mobile
    {
        get { return _mobile; }
        set { if (value == "")message("لطفا شماره موبایل را وارد کنید"); _mobile = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfRegister
    {
        get { return _dateOfRegister; }
        set { _dateOfRegister = DateTimeNow(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { if (value == "")message("لطفا نام را وارد کنید"); _name = value; }
    }

    public string Family
    {
        get { return _family; }
        set { if (value == "")message("لطفا نام خانوادگی را وارد کنید"); _family = value; }
  }

   public  void edit()
   {
       _BUuser._VOUser=this;
       _BuUser.Edituser();
   }
}
```

So and in another Business layer  I want to create a method that can Edit my record in the database. I pass the user value object to Business layer and my Business  layer does this operation via the following function :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using novitiate.DataAccesslayer;
using novitiate.ValueObjectLayer;

namespace novitiate.BusinessLayer
{
    public class BUUser:BuMainClass
    {
        protected DataAccesslayer.tblUser _userDA;
        public ValueObjectLayer.VOuser _VOUser;

    public BUUser()
    {
        _userDA=new tblUser();
    }

    public  bool AddUser()
    {
        _userDA.userName = _VOUser.Username;
        _userDA.password = _VOUser.Password;
        _userDA.email = _VOUser.Email;
        _userDA.mobile = _VOUser.Mobile;
        _userDA.dateOfRegister = _VOUser.DateOfRegister;
        _userDA.name = _VOUser.Name;
        _userDA.family = _VOUser.Family;
        dbconnect.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(_userDA);
        dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Edituser()
    {
        _userDA.userName = _VOUser.Username;
        _userDA.password = _VOUser.Password;
        _userDA.email = _VOUser.Email;
        _userDA.mobile = _VOUser.Mobile;
        _userDA.dateOfRegister = _VOUser.DateOfRegister;
        _userDA.name = _VOUser.Name;
        _userDA.family = _VOUser.Family;
        dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I call the edit function in user object layer.

My question is on the Edit function. Do you think that the model I use is working or I should use some thing like this :

```
public bool Edituser()
{
    var q = from i in dbconnect.tblUsers where i.userName == _VOUser.Username select i;

    q.First().password = _VOUser.Password;
    q.First().email = _VOUser.Email;
    q.First().mobile = _VOUser.Mobile;
    q.First().dateOfRegister = _VOUser.DateOfRegister;
    q.First().name = _VOUser.Name;
    q.First().family = _VOUser.Family;
    dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
```

I want to edit my record without Select query. I just want to pass my NEW User value object to my Edit function and my function just calls submit.change();
And every thing be ok ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look on your code

```
public bool Edituser()
{
    var q = from i in dbconnect.tblUsers 
            where i.userName == _VOUser.Username 
            select i;

    q.First().userName = _VOUser.Username;
    q.First().password = _VOUser.Password;
    q.First().email = _VOUser.Email;
    q.First().mobile = _VOUser.Mobile;
    q.First().dateOfRegister = _VOUser.DateOfRegister;
    q.First().name = _VOUser.Name;
    q.First().family = _VOUser.Family;
    dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
```

What happens here - you are executing query each time when you call `First()`. So, you defined query to select user by name. Then you query for first user and set its name (why?). Then you again query for first user and set its password. Then you again query for first user and set its email. etc

What you need is query user once, then update it and submit changes:

```
public bool Edituser()
{
    var user = 
        dbconnect.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == _VOUser.Username);

    if (user == null)
        // throw exception

    user.password = _VOUser.Password;
    user.email = _VOUser.Email;
    user.mobile = _VOUser.Mobile;
    user.dateOfRegister = _VOUser.DateOfRegister;
    user.name = _VOUser.Name;
    user.family = _VOUser.Family;
    dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Note - you can use mapping tool to map properties between entities automatically. E.g. AutoMapper will do it for you:

```
public bool Edituser()
{
    var user = 
        dbconnect.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == _VOUser.Username);

    if (user == null)
        // throw exception

    Mapper.Map(_VOUser, user);
    dbconnect.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Also I would move data-access related operations to separate class, like `UserRepository`. One more thing that looks strange to me is that your `Edituser()` does not accept user which should be updated. I'd expects signature like `public bool Update(VOuser voUser)`

Comment: yes ,it is my fault ,but i just need to map my user value object to my tbluser

Comment: and my question is can i use *** var user = 
        dbconnect.tblUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userName == _VOUser.Username);*** this query in Business layer

Comment: @SSC having queries in Business Layer is not very good idea - you should keep them in Data Access Layer

Comment: :I can't find  Mapper.Map(_VOUser, user);

Comment: @SSC have you added [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to your project? Also don't forget to create map